# 1960's book about a stowaway on a moon rocket

Tags: story-identification, books, moon

I remember a book about a worker who got caught in a moon rocket, crashed through the crust and survived.

Was joined by a chimp named Cheeky who was in the rocket and met a moon man with translucent skin and a cosmonaut who turned out to be his brother.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! This is very terse; if you want to improve it, see [this great guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) for some help.

Comment: From the question title, I was about to answer with *Miss Pickerell on the Moon* -- but never mind.

Comment: Ah, Miss Pickerell. A name I’ve not heard since the early Seventies.

Answer (score 3):

[One Against the Moon](https://books.google.com/books?id=DhijCwAAQBAJ) by Donald A. Wollheim

> When Robin Carew is mistakenly thrust into space in what is meant to
>   be an unmanned craft, he is forced to explore the moon terrain for
>   food and water. While there, he also discovers strange animals and an
>   alien-being.

Comment: There’s a name which does not make me think in any way that the story will be derivative of Robinson Crusoe.

Comment: That is it!  Thank you profusely!